# If condition is met then run multiple ifs

Tags: excel, match, background-color, vba

I am trying to execute a bunch of IF statements when ONE statement is met, yeah it sounds strange, but I cannot wrap my head around what I need to do.

Essentially I want to count "c" in cells(i, j) for j = 1 to 6 and i for i = 1 to unbound(a) (no more rows). Then if it counts c >= 3 then it should execute all these if statements to give the matching cells an Index color. Of course my code is very crude and inefficient, so change it as you see fit. I am still learning VBA, and I love doing it in my free time, the possibilities are endless!

I hope it makes sense what it is I am trying to do.

```
Sub Visrigtige()Dim b(48) As Boolean, x, a
Dim c, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, f As Long, g As Long, h As Long


Columns("A:F").Interior.Color = xlNone
Range("M2:R2").Interior.Color = xlNone


    Cells(2, "m").Interior.ColorIndex = 34
    Cells(2, "n").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    Cells(2, "o").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Cells(2, "p").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Cells(2, "q").Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    Cells(2, "r").Interior.ColorIndex = 40


x = Array(Range("M2"), Range("N2"), Range("O2"), Range("P2"), Range("Q2"),     Range("R2")) 'change this to suit, or use input box or other


a = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 6).Rows
For Each c In x: b(c) = True: Next c
For i = 1 To UBound(a)
c = 0
For j = 1 To 6
    If b(a(i, j)) Then c = c + 1
    Next j
        If c >= 3 Then
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "m") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "n") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "o") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "p") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "q") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "r") Then Cells(i,     j).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Do you guys know what is wrong with the last portion of my code?

Specifically this part:

```
If b(a(i, j)) Then c = c + 1        Next j
        If c >= 3 Then
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "m") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "n") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "o") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "p") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "q") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
            If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "r") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does an error occur? If yes, at which line?

Comment: `b(a(i, j))` expects to result in a boolean (true and false) value. As it is now there is nothing that creates a `TRUE/FALSE` value. I don't know what your goal is. Can you give us the data in your spreadsheet. What are the values in `Range("A1:A6")`.

Comment: I think it would be more readable to use SELECT CASE for the coloring index part.

Comment: @JulianKuchlbauer It does nothing. And sometimes when I change the code a bit it tells me that I cannot "Next without for".

@Spurious in `Range("A1:A6")` are a row if random numbers. If they match with `Range("M2:Q2")` in any order c should be counted `c = c + 1`. Only when I've gotten 3 matches `Range("A1:A6")` with `Range("M2:Q2")` should the following be run. But since my the numbers can be in any order i need to search for the cell that has the correct background color and then highlight it. `If Cells(i, j) = Cells(2, "m") Then Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 34`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay guys, I figured it out myself.

```
Sub Visrigtige()
Dim b(48) As Boolean, x, a
Dim c, i As Long, j As Long
Dim k As Long

Columns("A:G").Interior.Color = xlNone
Range("M2:R2").Interior.Color = xlNone

    Cells(2, "m").Interior.ColorIndex = 34
    Cells(2, "n").Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    Cells(2, "o").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Cells(2, "p").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    Cells(2, "q").Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    Cells(2, "r").Interior.ColorIndex = 40

x = Array(Range("M2"), Range("N2"), Range("O2"), Range("P2"), Range("Q2"), Range("R2")) 'change this to suit, or use input box or other

a = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 6).Rows
For Each c In x: b(c) = True: Next c
For i = 1 To UBound(a)
c = 0
For j = 1 To 6
    If b(a(i, j)) Then c = c + 1
    Next j
    For k = 1 To 6
    If c >= 3 And Cells(i, k) = Cells(2, "m") Then Cells(i, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 34
    If c >= 3 And Cells(i, k) = Cells(2, "n") Then Cells(i, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    If c >= 3 And Cells(i, k) = Cells(2, "o") Then Cells(i, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    If c >= 3 And Cells(i, k) = Cells(2, "p") Then Cells(i, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    If c >= 3 And Cells(i, k) = Cells(2, "q") Then Cells(i, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
    If c >= 3 And Cells(i, k) = Cells(2, "r") Then Cells(i, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
    Next k
Next i
End Sub
```

Not sure if you can see what I did, but i Dim k as long and made a new loop my code to check.